# How to serve different DocumentRoot's in apache based on extension?

Tags: apache-http-server

Sorry, I'm sure this is super basic, but I can't find an example that lets me serve different `DocumentRoot` directories based on the url **extension** (though I see plenty of examples to serve different `DocumentRoot` directories based on ServerName, ip address, etc.)

Here's my config right now:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    ServerName example.com
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem

  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

So going to `https://www.example.com/` serves `/var/www/html`. Fine. But now I want a specific extension to the url e.g. `https://www.example.com/wordpress` to serve up a completely different `DocumentRoot` directory (e.g. `/home/me/wordpress`). What is the best way to configure apache to achieve this (and without having to repeat all the SSL config)?

Comment: Lookup the `Alias` directive.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't find an example that lets me serve different `DocumentRoot` directories based on the url extension.

I don't believe this is possible (assuming you mean using the actual `DocumentRoot` directive).

However, as pointed out in the comments, `Alias` (via [mod_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html)) can likely do what you wish ex.:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem

        Alias "/wordpress" "/home/me/wordpress"

        # This can potentially help with permission issues.
        <Directory "/home/me/wordpress">
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Another potential option is to use a symbolic link to ex. `/home/me/wordpress` (e.g. directly in `/var/www/html` as `wordpress`).